How do i refresh standard component? - OppLineItem
I have an Lwc button triggering the integration and upon success retrieve its not refreshing the component. How can i refresh the component? As of now, until i refresh the whole page or refresh the component manually, is when the data comes through.
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import getPriceForOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/AccessTokenService.getPriceForOpportunity';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class CheckPriceButton extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    isLoading = false;

    handleClick() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        console.log('Opportunity ID: ', this.recordId);

        getPriceForOpportunity({ opportunityId: this.recordId })
            .then(() => {
                this.showToast('Success', 'Pricing has been successfully updated!', 'success');
                window.location.reload()
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                this.showToast('Error', `An error occurred: ${error.body.message}`, 'error');
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title,
            message,
            variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    get buttonLabel() {
        return this.isLoading ? 'Processing...' : 'Check Price';
    }

    get buttonDisabled() {
        return this.isLoading;
    }
}

this is part of the apex,
@AuraEnabled
public static void getPriceForOpportunity(String opportunityId) {
    try {
        Opportunity opp = [
            SELECT Id, Account.Master_Data_GUID__c, Account.Address_Country_List__c, CurrencyIsoCode
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id = :opportunityId 
            LIMIT 1
        ];

        List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = [
            SELECT Id, Product2.Master_Data_GUID__c 
            FROM OpportunityLineItem 
            WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunityId
        ];

        if (opp == null || lineItems.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Opportunity or related products not found.');
        }

        String mdAccountId = opp.Account.Master_Data_GUID__c; // Fetch MDAccountId
        String currencyCode = opp.CurrencyIsoCode; // Fetch CurrencyIsoCode
        String countryCode = opp.Account.Address_Country_List__c; // Fetch CountryCode for standard price

        // Create a list to hold all updated line items
        List<OpportunityLineItem> updatedLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

        // Loop through each OpportunityLineItem
        for (OpportunityLineItem lineItem : lineItems) {
            String mdProductId = lineItem.Product2.Master_Data_GUID__c;

            // Debug the data being sent to the API
            System.debug('MDAccountId: ' + mdAccountId);
            System.debug('MDProductId: ' + mdProductId);
            System.debug('CurrencyCode: ' + currencyCode);
            System.debug('CountryCode: ' + countryCode);

            // Prepare the payload for the Customer Price API request
            Map<String, Object> requestPayloadCustomerPrice = new Map<String, Object>{
                'MDProductId' => mdProductId,
                'CurrencyCode' => currencyCode,
                'MDAccountId' => mdAccountId,  // Include MDAccountId for Customer Price
                'CountryCode' => countryCode  // Include CountryCode for Customer Price
            };

            // Prepare the payload for the Standard Price API request
            Map<String, Object> requestPayloadStandardPrice = new Map<String, Object>{
                'MDProductId' => mdProductId,
                'CurrencyCode' => currencyCode,
                'MDAccountId' => mdAccountId,  // Include MDAccountId for Standard Price
                'CountryCode' => countryCode  // Include CountryCode for Standard Price
            };

            String requestBodyCustomer = JSON.serialize(requestPayloadCustomerPrice);
            String requestBodyStandard = JSON.serialize(requestPayloadStandardPrice);

            // Fetch price from both customer and standard endpoints
            OpportunityLineItem updatedItem = fetchValidAccessTokenAndPrice(requestBodyCustomer, requestBodyStandard, lineItem);
            if (updatedItem != null) {
                updatedLineItems.add(updatedItem); // Only add if price is found
            }
        }

        // Now, update all the line items in one DML operation
        if (!updatedLineItems.isEmpty()) {
            update updatedLineItems;
            System.debug('Successfully updated all Opportunity Line Items with retrieved prices.');
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('An error occurred while processing: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}



You may import RefreshEvent and then fire it:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import getPriceForOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/AccessTokenService.getPriceForOpportunity';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class CheckPriceButton extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    isLoading = false;

    handleClick() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        console.log('Opportunity ID: ', this.recordId);

        getPriceForOpportunity({ opportunityId: this.recordId })
            .then(() => {
                this.showToast('Success', 'Pricing has been successfully updated!', 'success');
                this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
            })
        ...

}
